# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First: Single column foreign-key to multiple entities

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I've been trying to create model in EF 4.1 to represent a database schema with a single table and column holding foreign keys from two other tables, but have had little luck with both annotations and the fluent API.  A sample model is shown here:

```
public class User
{
    ...
    public virtual ExtendedAttribute ExtendedAttributes { get; set; }
}    

public class Account
{
    ...
    public virtual ExtendedAttribute ExtendedAttributes { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedAttribute
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public Guid ItemId {get; set;} // both Account.Id and User.Id stored here
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Currently the configuration for these entities looks something like this for both User and Account modelBuilders:

```
this.HasOptional(u => u.ExtendedAttributes).WithRequired();
```

Any thoughts on how to do achieve?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is even not possible with the database itself and EF will not put any abstraction for that. You must have separate column and navigation property for each entity.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ladislav.  Though I was able to create a database with the foreign key relationships set up as I described (which is weird), you're absolutely correct in that I'm unable to insert actual data as such.  So I suppose the option is then to map the keys to multiple columns, or create a one-to-one intermediary to do the mapping.  Suggestions on the preferred method in this case?